# Press enter to close a window in Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm playing a game and alongside the game .exe I also run another .exe that runs a personal program I'm developing (it records information that I can then monitor outside the game.)

One of the .exe's opens a cmd window, which I'd then like to immediately close at the end of the .bat.

Pressing enter manually will close the window, however, I don't know how to automate the enter keypress.

All I want to do is automate the pressing of the enter key after both the exes have been launched.

Should be simple to do I guess! but looked around for a while and can't find a solution.

Thanks.

the code for my very very basic batch:

```
start "" "E:\World of Warcraft\Wow-64.exe"
start "" "C:\Users\Kek\Desktop\New folder\DocumentAll.exe"
```

Comment: completely depands, how the exe processes keystrokes. The easiest thing, you can try is `echo/|yourexe.exe`

Comment: which .exe would that be for? one of the .exes makes a command prompt signalling that is is running, and this is the window I'd like to close.

Comment: How should we be able to help you if you do not even show the code of the batch file?

Comment: added code for the batch